# How to permanently fix Xcode 5 SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5, springboard

Launching apps from Xcode 5 to the iOS simulator (multiple OS versions) fails with `SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3`. I can get around the problem by 'turning it off and back on again' (quitting the simulator and relaunching, uninstalling and redeploying the app, etc.), but it seems to come back again later and in other projects.

Can someone help me understand what the real problem here is and if there is a permanent fix?

Comment: I also get this error quite frequently even after resetting the content and settings of the simulator

Comment: Most of the answerers below seem to have neglected to read your question, since you said you have tried quitting/resetting but it keeps happening later.
This is a recurring problem for me too, seems to happen more with XCode 5.

Comment: @shim - yes, that's why I haven't chosen an answer yet. I know how to workaround it, but I would really like to understand what's causing it and how to resolve it altogether.

Comment: Interesting that Bill the Lizard points to an old link dealing with an unrelated error code and says there is already an answer. As Kyle says, he knows the workaround! He (and I and probably loads of others) would like to know the cause and/or the fix for this issue.

Comment: Agreed, I think this question needs to be re-opened. The duplicate message even says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question". The new question is: How to fix the issue **permanently**.

Comment: @KyleClegg I don't have privileges to vote for reopen, but I've flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: Check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855222/springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3/20236097#20236097

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why, but on my end deleting the app from simulator solved this.

Comment: I had to change the simulated device once also.

Comment: many different answers to the same issue .. but none is giving the 'reason' why it happens... all answers are just one way to bypass the issue tip next time...

Comment: @erwin I think that's just a bug Apple should fix.

Comment: Again, a temporary solution only. I get this problem even when starting a fresh new project.

Comment: @JosephHumfrey Do you use latest Xcode?

Comment: @Idan Yep, using version 5.0.2 (5A3005).

Answer (score 11):

Quitting simulator seems to help.

Answer (score 4):

Run Activity Monitor and force Kill the simulator process. Then Run you app again and simulator will launch automatically and problem goes away.

Comment: active simulator window, then press Command + Q is more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be because you have installed (run) it on 64bit iOS7 simulator and now you are trying to use same install/files on 32bit simulation.

Comment: I believe this is the answer.  I've switched between 64 bit and regular iOS Simulator and when I try to run 32 bit, it throws the Spring Board -3 error.  If I run in 64 bit, it loads without a problem.

Comment: Perhaps some truth in there something (related to new 64 bit simulator), but this isn't the entire answer. I've started a fresh new project without switching, and I still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

1) Press stop button from Xcode

2) Exit Simulator

3) Press run button again from Xcode

This is the quickest workaround that I have tried, did not have to delete the app or do anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Restart simulator, if it wont solve your problem and then delete all content. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I started getting this error when manually editing files that are in the Emulator's disk space.

With "the Emulator's disk space" I mean a path similar to this one:
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications//.app/

Having the build process re-run solved my problems too so I feel like it has something to do with file permissions or some sort of checksum failure.