# SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5, springboard

I'm getting an warning as 'SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3'. This happens when trying to run application in Xcode 5.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently fix Xcode 5 SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883942/how-to-permanently-fix-xcode-5-springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-err)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287526/why-springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Finally...found solution!

**Solution 1** : **Just quit Simulator and clean Xcode.** The fresh build will not show this Alert again. The possible reason for this might be switching between 64-bit simulator and 32-bit simulator.

**Solution 2** : If the problem still persists then **delete the App from Simulator** and re-run the code. This will work since the app contents are freshly loaded.

Springboard (also known as Home Screen) is the standard application that manages the iOS home screen.

Also, these may be bug of Xcode 5.0.2. I haven't encountered any such error in Xcode 5.1 (Beta) version.

Answer (score 13):

just close the simulator, clean it your project, built it again, and launch again. Its work on me.

Answer (score 3):

It also works to clean your code and then go to iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings. Just an alternative if you don't want to close and reopen your Simulator (mine takes forever to quit and reopen)

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.

After trying what evanhutomo failed for me, I tried a slight variation.

- Install 6.1 simulator
- Run in 6.1 simulator
- When it fails you should be dropped on the spring board
- Delete the application.
- Try building again

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the app from the simulator and then rebuilding and running helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions here, but none worked. From another SO answer I tried setting App Support/iPhone Simulator directory recursively to 777 permissions.

$sudo chmod -R 777 "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/"

I'm not recommending this, just saying it took care of the problem for me!