# Fix XCode Errors about Simulator in use and lost connection

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

These errors keep happening from time to time when i run my app. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or rhythm to when the errors happen. Sometimes I can run and quit my app 100 times and not see these. Sometimes every 5 times they will show up. They go away but they are slowing down the dev process. How can I fix the underlying issue?

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1VMK.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgj4s.png]

Comment: common problem, no fix as far as i know

Comment: SpringBoard issue can be resolved using this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855222/springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3/20236097#20236097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, these 3 cases occur in 3 different scenarios.

1. "***Springboard Error***" is a common iOS simulator issue since Xcode 5.

   - It has no fix, as yet, other than restarting the iOS simulator.
     .
2. "***lost connection***" occurs when you disconnect the device or quit the simulator prematurely.
   (*example: click run and then stop it almost immediately*)
3. "***Simulator in use***" occurs when you're already running, say, `ABC` xcode project in the iOS simulator and you want to run another Xcode project, say, `XYZ` project in the iOS simulator simultaneously.

   - Go to `ABC` project, stop it and **then** run `XYZ` project.