# iPhone Simulator: failed to launch application with error: 3?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 5 for implement iOS application. Sometime i am getting this type of error when running my application,Shown below

I searched in google people suggested that Hard reset simulator,i reset simulator but again i am facing this popup, can anyone tell me how can i resolved this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855222/springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consistent issue with XCode 5. Updating was supposed to fix this, but apparently has not. The best way to deal with it is simply totally quit the simulator (command + q not just press the x) and launch again.

Comment: I know that your suggestion solves this issue, but you know where it comes from ?

Comment: If you look at their release notes for 5.1 they talk about simulator error hangups and recommend just quitting and restarting. Although they have not recognized this particular issue in their release notes (as it is not resolved...) Look here for more: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW2

Comment: yes i know this is temporary solution.it consume a lot of time,is there any solution by which i will not face this this type of error,

Comment: No. I don't think so. It is an error with XCode. It's just going to be annoying until they solve it.

Comment: The other solution is to run it on your iPhone.