# Black launchscreen

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently have a problem when I run my application.
My LaunchScreen is black and I have the following message inside the console:

```
objc[4358]: class `SpringBoard' not linked into application
CoreFoundation = 1240.100000
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it related to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883942/how-to-permanently-fix-xcode-5-springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-err)? If yes, they are suggesting restarting the simulator.